# I am getting this error like index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom hook that returns a register method to set reference to the input field in the component.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

import { Form } from './Form';

const useFormsio = ( STATE ) => {

    const [ refs, setRefs ] = useState({});

    const register = (fieldArgs) => {
        const inputRef = useRef();
        const key = Object.keys(fieldArgs);
        //console.log(fieldArgs);
        useEffect(() => {
            setRefs(prevState => {
                return{
                    ...prevState,
                    [key]: inputRef
                }
            })
        }, [ fieldArgs ])

        return inputRef;
    }

    return [ Form, register ];
}

export { useFormsio };
```

And the component as below, It contains the input fields, using register method i am passing the field name to set the reference.

```
const App = () => {
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
        userName: '',
        userEmail: ''
    };
    const [ Form, register ] = useFormsio(INITIAL_STATE);
    return(
        <Form>

            <input
                type = 'text'
                placeholder = 'Enter your name'
                name = 'userName'
                data-validations = { register({ name:'userName' })} />

            <input
                type = 'email'
                placeholder = 'Enter your email'
                name = 'userEmail'
                data-validations = { register({ name:'userEmail' })} />

            <button
                type = 'submit'>
                    Submit
            </button>

        </Form>
    )
}
```

Why i am getting error like this?

Comment: `setRefs()` causes a state update which causes a rerender. On each render you are calling `register()` which internally calls `setRefs()`. This is giving you a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you're running in an infinite loop of re-renders. You should put your `register()` inside a lifecycle method. Something on these lines-

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    register(fieldArgs);
},[fieldArgs])

 const register = (fieldArgs) => {
    const inputRef = useRef();
    const key = Object.keys(fieldArgs);
    //console.log(fieldArgs);
    
        setRefs(prevState => {
            return{
                ...prevState,
                [key]: inputRef
            }
        })
    

    return inputRef;
}
```